# Adding J Table content to MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlexception

I coded for setting JTable contents to the MySQL database. Invoice no is getting by a text field. Other data is in the J table.

The code is available below;

```
        String invoice = InvoiceNo_txt.getText(); 
        String id = (String) tableSale.getValueAt(i, 0);
        String name = (String) tableSale.getValueAt(i, 1);
        double dcost =  (double) tableSale.getValueAt(i, 2);
        String cost = String.valueOf(dcost);//converting double to string
        double dqty = (double) tableSale.getValueAt(i, 3);
        String qty = String.valueOf(dqty);//converting double to string
        double ditemDiscount = (double) tableSale.getValueAt(i, 4);
        String itemDiscount = String.valueOf(ditemDiscount);//converting double to string
        double dgrossTotal = (double) tableSale.getValueAt(i, 5);
        String grossTotal = String.valueOf(dgrossTotal);//converting double to string

    try{
            String sql2 = "Insert into tablesaleinfo (InvoiceNo,ItemID,ItemName,Cost,QtySold,ItemDiscount,GrossTotal)values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

            pst.setString(1, invoice);
            pst.setString(2, id);
            pst.setString(3, name);
            pst.setString(4, cost);
            pst.setString(5, qty);
            pst.setString(6, itemDiscount);
            pst.setString(7, grossTotal);

            pst.execute();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New  Data Saved...");


        }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I keep getting the error `java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7)`.

Stack Trace is below;

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7).
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3399)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4110)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.add_btnActionPerformed(Newsale.java:670)
at com.bit.project.Newsale.access$700(Newsale.java:38)
at com.bit.project.Newsale$10.actionPerformed(Newsale.java:431)
```

What is the error here ?

Comment: Get your SQL statements sorted before you go slapping the Swing and `JTable` tags on a post!

Comment: Count the number of column names and `?`s in your `INSERT`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic my mistake thanks :)